# Why are not all the pictures from kaggle uploaded on the google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I started using google colab for ML,i use a dataset with more than 80.000 pictures from kaggle,i have the following problems:
1.I tested with Kaggle and is stopping on 6 epochs,basicly performance issue I think,there is no error.
2.I tried to move on google colab but i don't know why after unzip is not unzipping all the pictures even if i have space on google drive .
Can you please give me any suggestion on 1 or 2 how can i solve this issue ?
2-not all files are unzipped
1-is stoping to quick
Or if you know any other site that i can use?

I tried unzipping more than twice the arhive and even i uploaded the folders manually on the drive
And also i am getting this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXSZK.png)